# Nodejs array matching

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have an array that contains the path-api mapping as below:

```
var apiArray = [
  {
    "api" : "login",
    "path" : "/auth/login",
    "method" : "POST"
  },
  {
    "api" : "logout",
    "path" : "/auth/logout/{sessionId}",
    "method" : "POST"
  },
  {
    "api" : "getAsset",
    "path" : "/asset/{Id}",
    "method" : "GET"
  },
  {
    "api" : "getAssetScheme",
    "path" : "/asset/Scheme/{Id}",
    "method" : "GET"
  }
];
```

Whenever a request is made to service, i need to match the url in the http request to the path property in the above array to find out which api is invoked. something like

```
function getApiName(apiArray, reqPath){

  // compares reqPath with the path property of each element in the array
  // returns the name of the api for path that matched.
  for(var i=0; i < apiArray.length;i++){
     if(apiArray[i].path=== reqPath) return apiArray[i].api;
  }
  return null;
}
```

for a simple api which does not have path or query parameter, this logic works fine. But it fails for the cases :
1. apis with path parameter: ex: logout, getAsset which have a path parameter (sessionId and Id respectively). In this cases, 
reqPath ="/auth/logout/55ffc09e56eb79c737c7aac6". 
2. apis with query parameters:   Here,
reqPath ="/tree/getTree/?subTree=true&&type=node".

How can i modify my function 'getApiName' to support apis with query and path parameters?

Also, i might have to support a scenario where path of one api is substring of other: i.e when my array has entries as below 
 api 1: path="/asset/"
 api 2: path="/assset/scheme/"

Comment: please edit your code.  ident with 4 spaces for readability, or highlight the code and click on { } button i the textedit toolbar

Comment: I think you can use express module to handle the URL

Comment: Do you manually define the apiArray[] ?

Comment: @NidhinDavid api array is extracted from another js file which contains api description like<br/>exports.logout = {
  spec: {
    description: "Logout the user from cartos application",
    path: "/auth/logout/{sessionId}",
    method: "POST",
    summary: "Logout the user from cartos application",
application.",
    type: "User",
    parameters: [{
        name: "sessionId",
        description: "Session Id to be logged out",
        required: true,
        type: "string",
        paramType: "path"
      }],
  },
  action: //do something
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `npm install --save lodash`

Case 1:
if you cannot edit path key add a new key containg the regular expresion otherwise edit path key for path for all objects of apiArray[]
eg:

`"path" : new RegExp("/auth/logout/*";`

Then use lodash library to quickely find the matching object;

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var apiArray = [
    {
        "api": "login",
        "path": new RegExp("/auth/login"),
        "method": "POST"
    },
    {
        "api": "logout",
        "path": new RegExp("/auth/logout/*"),
        "method": "POST"
    },
    {
        "api": "getAsset",
        "path": new RegExp("/asset/*"),
        "method": "GET"
    },
    {
        "api": "getAssetScheme",
        "path": new RegExp("/asset/Scheme/*"),
        "method": "GET"
    }
];
var url = '/asset/frew'
var api = _.find(apiArray, function(item){
    return item.path.test(url);
});
console.log(api);
```

This returns the object that contains the matching path from which you can extrat the api

case 2:

Split the reqPath at '?' and feed url to the above find function

```
const reqPath ="/tree/getTree/?subTree=true&&type=node";
const url = reqPath.split('?')[0];
```

Comment: @KavyaMugali Start using lodash library. It has lot of functions that make coding a lot easy. http://www.lodash.com

Answer (score 0):

```
if(apiArray[i].path=== reqPath).
```

You are doing string comparison, so wont work for all cases(as path, query parameters changes).

So my suggestion is compare `BASE URL`:

baseurl wont change so you can do string compare.

```
var apiArray=[

     {
            "api" : "login",
            "path" : "/auth/login",
            "baseurl":"/auth/login"
           "method" : "POST"
         },
         {
           "api" : "logout",
           "path" : "/auth/logout/{sessionId}",
           "baseurl":"/auth/logout/"
           "method" : "POST"
         }]


function getApiName(apiArray, reqbaseurl){

  // compares reqPath with the path property of each element in the array
  // returns the name of the api for path that matched.
  for(var i=0; i < apiArray.length;i++){
     if(apiArray[i].baseurl=== reqbaseurl) return apiArray[i].api;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Are you using Express?. If yes then handle using express module.

Comment: I get the path from my api documentation (as recognized by swagger ie. path="/auth/logout/{sessionId}"). How can i get base url from that? Also, yes i use express. Please suggest how i can handle this situation using express?

Comment: @KavyaMugali in express i think u  implemented the above route right? If yes then just print the req.url of the invoked route.